# How to set up Chatter messages visibility?

Tags: community, chatter, partner-communities, visibility

We want to let community users send messages via Chatter to all users in the system BUT we don't what them to see conversations between other users.

e.g. we have partnerA, partnerB and userA. PartnerB can see communications between partnerA and userA and this is wrong.

Is there a way to configure Chatter for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control user visibility to a certain extent with [User Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_external_user_settings.htm&language=en_US), but when you're collaborating with Chatter, there are certain situations in which it's not possible for the users to be completely hidden from each other.

For example, any user can access a public group. So if partnerA and userA are having a discussion in a public group, partnerB will be able to read the thread and know of partnerA's existence -- partnerB could even comment in the thread. I can see why this was done, because it would make for a confusing experience to hide posts/comments/@mentions from non-shared users in public threads.

Answer (score 1):

Winter '15 release introduces a new profile permission that can enable/disable Chatter for user profiles and give customers the control over who can use Chatter and who can not.
See below for more information:
 ​http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_pbr.htm#collab_pbr&language=en

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think Profile-Based Rollout of Chatter will help in this case. All three of the users in the example have Chatter turned on, because that's how they're collaborating.